# Switching on HTTP Activation in IIS

Tags: content-delivery

In the [documentation for setting up a .NET content delivery site](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-D1A69CDD-A7B0-452B-99BD-F01150102D90) for SDL Web 8, is written:  `Ensure that in IIS, the WCF Service feature "HTTP Activation" is switched on.`

I have been able to add "HTTP Activation" as a server feature using the Windows Server Manager, under:

```
|---- .NET Framework 4.5 Features (Installed) 
  | ---- WCF Services (Installed)
     | ---- HTTP Activation (Installed)
```

I don't see any settings for this in the IIS snap-in. Is this sufficient, or do I have further configurations to make in IIS?

Comment: This is sufficient !

Comment: Sayantan - maybe you should give that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! That is sufficient to enable HTTP activation from IIS.